# How i can use laravel Event Listner to send mail notification before an event

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-events

I am Trying to achieve a feature in my laravel Project. I am currently doing an Event related project. And there is Event start date and Event voting start date etc. The voting will be start at a date set on the database. How i can send a notification using Laravel Event Listner feature that the Voting will be starting tomorrow. How i can set the listeners and events in this case.

I already know laravel scheduler, using scheduler i can send email notification. But using scheduler i have to check every day in the database that the date is reached or not. Without checking this how can i manage this using Laravel Event Listeners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events do not support dates or time in this way, so you'll have to use some additional behavior to check when the "start date" is the current time, and then have that behavior fire the event. You are correct that Laravel's scheduler would be a good fit for this.

Comment: Thanks. I also feel so.